# How fix defaut material dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

Please help fix angular 2 material dialog-component.

I tried to start the dialog component in the simplest form. [Here's](http://fh79272k.bget.ru/files/dialog/) what I got. The problem is that after clicking on the button the dialog opens with a large offset relative to the edge of the screen. In addition, the console displays the following error message:

> Error: No component factory found for ConvDialogComponent. Did you add
>   it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
>       at noComponentFactoryError (core.es5.js:3202)

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MdButtonModule, MdDialogModule } from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ConvDialogComponent } from './conv-dialog/conv-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ConvDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MdDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { MdDialog } from '@angular/material';

import { ConvDialogComponent } from './conv-dialog/conv-dialog.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  selectedOption: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {};

    private openMoneyConverter(): void {
        console.log(111);
        this.dialog.open(ConvDialogComponent);
    };

}
```

conv-dialog.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-conv-dialog',
  templateUrl: './conv-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./conv-dialog.component.css']
})
export class ConvDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ConvDialogComponent` to `@NgModule.entryComponents`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ConvDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MdDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [ConvDialogComponent]
})
```